# Different I2C addresses on Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller, sensors, i2c

I've written a class for Arduino that reads the compass data of the [HiTechnic LEGO Mindstorms compass sensor](http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NMC1034).

Using the Wire-library, I can very well fetch the data from the respective registers. In my library for Arduino I address the sensor by `0x01` which someone has done already [on the Arduino forums](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=124936.0). But everywhere else on the web ([RobotC-forums for LEGO Mindstorms](http://www.robotc.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=463) or [in the code example at the very bottom of this document](http://stormingrobots.com/prod/tutorial/Compass%20Tutorial.pdf)) it says, the I2C address of that sensor was `0x02`.

So why do I have to use the address `0x01` in order to communicate with my sensor while it seems to be `0x02` for other programming languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different formats of I2C addresses - 7 or 8 bits. Arduino uses the 7-bit format, so to convert an 8-bit address to 7-bits, you just shift it right by one. That's how the 0x02 8-bit address is converted to the 0x01 7-bit address.

Source: http://arduino.cc/en/reference/wire

> "Note:
>   There are both 7- and 8-bit versions of I2C addresses. 7 bits identify the device, and the eighth bit determines if it's being written to or read from. The Wire library uses 7 bit addresses throughout. If you have a datasheet or sample code that uses 8 bit address, you'll want to drop the low bit (i.e. shift the value one bit to the right), yielding an address between 0 and 127."

Comment: That seems to be it. Thank you.